# Как подтянуть код страны при выборе города?

Tags: php, html

Есть поле select со Странами и поле input с номером телефона.
Из бд в select передаются все страны. как сделать, что бы когда я выбираю страну автоматически потягивался во второй input код страны для телефона. В базе все данные есть. Не пойму как связать 2 поля.
делаю так

```html
<select id="countries_phone1" class="form-control bfh-countries"  data-country="US">
                <?php foreach ($country as $value) {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $value['iso']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></option>
                <?php }?>
            </select>
            <input type="text" class="form-control bfh-phone" data-country="countries_phone1">
```

Comment: Данные подставляются из БД? Как в смысле таблиц устроена эта связь в базе? Данные уже загружены из бд или запрос строится в момент выбора первого селекта?

Comment: В базе  есть, Страны, их номера и тд Я через foreach вывожу данные в option селекта

Comment: Все данные хранятся в одной таблице или это несколько таблиц связанных ключами?

Comment: одна и там все данные. Название страны, код для телефона к этой стране и iso страны

Comment: В вашем коде я ни разу не вижу sql-запроса к базе, возможно он расположен в коде выше. Здесь же вы в цикле foreach() перебираете полученные из бд строки. Два поля - iso и name вы подставляете при создании селекта. Далее цикл ваш заканчивается. Я всё ещё надеюсь, что где-то выше до указанного вами фрагмента сохранены все результаты запроса, где есть и телефонные коды стран. С другой стороны, ваш инпут находится вне цикла, где формируется селект. Очевидно, вам надо отследить (и я не помню как это реализовано в php) изменение селекта.

Comment: И затем считывать значение выбранной в селекте страны, и в новом цикле перебирать снова все результаты запроса и брать поле с телефонным кодом страны из той строки. где, например, совпадают поля iso или name.

Comment: Забыл добавить значения phone. Думаю через js смогу сделать при изменении селекта

Comment: Да, в js это можно отлично реализовать, если все результаты запроса к бд переданы в js.